# Extension method not listed on GetMethods()

Tags: c#, reflection

I've an extension method on `DateTime`:

```
public static DateTime? Year(this DateTime? datetime)
{
    return datetime;
}
```

And antoher one which is trying to build a `CallExpression` to this extension method:

```
public static Expression<Func<TElementType, DateTime?>> SemanticYear<TElementType>(this Expression<Func<TElementType, DateTime?>> expr)
{

    MethodInfo method = typeof(DateTime?).GetMethods().Where(m => m.Name.Equals("Year"));
    //<<<<<< returns null!!

    Expression<Func<TElementType, DateTime?>> lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<TElementType, DateTime?>>(
        Expression.Call(
            Expression.MakeMemberAccess(expr.Body, typeof(DateTime?).GetProperty("Value")),
            method
        ),
        expr.Parameters
    );

    return lambdaExpression;
}
```

Why do I unable to get `DateTime?.Year` extension method?

Both methods are implemented inside the same compilation unit:

```
namespace Backend.Infrastructure.Linq
{
    public static partial class LinqTreeExtensions
    {

        public static DateTime? Year(this DateTime datetime)
        {
        //....
        }

        public static Expression<Func<TElementType, DateTime?>> SemanticYear<TElementType>(this Expression<Func<TElementType, DateTime?>> expr)
        {
        //.......
        }
    }
}
```